# R function ambigous call

Tags: r

I'm working on a project, trying to convert an R function to CUDA C++, but I can't understand some R function call, I'm really new to R and I can't find what I'm really looking after. To be exactly, this is the main R function code:

```
for (i in 1:ncy) {
    res <- apply(allsubset, 2, banddepthforonecurve, xdata=x, ydata=y[,i], tau=tau, use=use)
    depth[i] <- sum(res[1,])
    localdepth[i] <- sum(res[2,])
  }
```

The part that I can't really understand is "banddepthforonecurve" function call, this is the "banddepthforonecurve" function code:

```
banddepthforonecurve <- function(x, xdata, ydata, tau, use) {
    envsup <- apply(xdata[,x], 1, max)
    envinf <- apply(xdata[,x], 1, min)
    inenvsup <- ydata <= envsup
    inenvinf <- ydata >= envinf
    depth <- all(inenvsup) & all(inenvinf)
    localdepth <- depth & use(envsup-envinf) <= tau
    res <- c(depth,localdepth)
    return(res)
  }
```

When it is called in:

```
res <- apply(allsubset, 2, banddepthforonecurve, xdata=x, ydata=y[,i], tau=tau, use=use)
```

I don't really get what it set for the first parameter "x" of the "banddepthforonecurve", I supposed its like `banddepthforonecurve(i, xdata=x, ydata=y[,i], tau = tau, use=use)`

but if I try to run it separately on R studio to try to understand it better I get:

```
apply(xdata[, x], 1, max) : dim(X) must have a positive length
```

Why when I compile the whole R project there isn't this error? What it set for the "x" parameter when called in the "res <- apply(...)"? I hope I was clear, sorry for my bad english, Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# This apply function
res = apply(X = input, MAR = 2, FUN = foo, ...)

# is essentially syntactical sugar for this:
res = list()
for(i in 1:ncol(X)) {
    res[[i]] = foo(X[, i], ...)
}
# plus an attempt simplify `res` (e.g., to a matrix or vector)
```

So in your line:

```
apply(allsubset, 2, banddepthforonecurve, xdata=x, ydata=y[,i], tau=tau, use=use)
```

In a single iteration of your for loop, the *first* parameter of `banddepthforonecurve` (`x`) will be `allubset[, 1]`, then `allsubset[, 2]`, ..., `allsubset[, ncol(allsubset)]`.

The `xdata` parameter is always `x`, the `tau` and `use` parameters are always `tau` and `use`, and the `for` loop iterates over the columns of `y` to use as the `ydata` argument. You can think of it as a nested loop, for each column of `y`, use it as `ydata` and (via `apply`) iterate over all columns of `allsubset`.

(If the `MAR` argument of apply was `1`, then it would iterate over *rows* instead of *columns*.)

Comment: Thank you very much ! That's exactly what I was searching !